# PHP variable visibility in a foreach statement

Tags: php

this is my code:

```
    $hash = 0;
    foreach ($this->championship->getRounds() as $round) {

        $ranking = $this->getRanking($round);
        echo "OLD_HASH: $hash, NEW_HASH: " . $ranking->getHash();
        if ($hash != $ranking->getHash()) {
            $ranking->fullUpdate();
        }
        $hash = $ranking->getHash();
        echo "SAVE_NEW: $hash";

        $matches = $this->getMatches($round);
        $matches ->fullUpdate();
    }
```

If I have 3 objects in the "Rounds" array, and the respective "hash" values are: 1, 2 and 3.

This is what I expect:

> OLD_HASH: 0, NEW_HASH: 1
>
> SAVE_NEW: 1
>
> OLD_HASH: 1, NEW_HASH: 2
>
> SAVE_NEW: 2
>
> OLD_HASH: 2, NEW_HASH: 3
>
> SAVE_NEW: 3

Instead this is the real result:

> OLD_HASH: 0, NEW_HASH: 1
>
> SAVE_NEW: 1
>
> OLD_HASH: 0, NEW_HASH: 2
>
> SAVE_NEW: 2
>
> OLD_HASH: 0, NEW_HASH: 3
>
> SAVE_NEW: 3

WHY?!?

Comment: Simply because you are changing the value of $hash each time

Comment: Is this correct: `ranking->getHash()`? Isn't there a `$` missing? This would cause a PHP warning, which does not execute that statement, and thus does not change `$hash` in `$hash = ranking->getHash()`.

Comment: @jibon57 Looks like you want to read the question again...

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a my mistake because I changed the code before paste it into the post. (I translated the variables name from italian to english)
But the issue persists.

Comment: You should be sure to know what exactly is happened. `var_dump` all - especially iterable array (may be there is only one iteration here)

Comment: Also, you probably fix your bug, while modifying your question for paste here :) double check you original variable names.

Comment: well, i can see nothing wrong with that? except possible the functions called (if they work as expected, it should work?)